# Is there a way to always order a table by a specific column in django-tables2?

Tags: django, django-tables2

I'm using `django-tables2` to render a table of `MyModel`. `MyModel` has a few different categories specified by its `category` field. I want to be able to overwrite `order_by` such that the table's primary ordering is always `category` and anything else selected is just a secondary ordering. Any suggestions on how I might do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else with this issue, I eventually got to an answer:

```
class PersonTable(tables.Table):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        def generate_order_func(field_name: str) -> Callable:
            # django-tables2 stamps any secondary ordering if you have a custom ordering function on any of your
            # ordering fields. This adds custom ordering to every field so that name is always the primary
            # ordering 

            def order_func(qs: QuerySet, descending: bool) -> Tuple[QuerySet, bool]:
                # Need custom ordering on deal_state (not alphabetical)
                qs = qs.order_by("name", ("-" if descending else "") + field_name)
                return qs, True

            return order_func

        for field in self._meta.fields:
            setattr(self, f"order_{field}", generate_order_func(field))

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This overwrites the ordering for each field such that it's ordered by the primary ordering firt.

Answer (score -1):

Late to forum.I haven't tried this below method. But it might help I think. Create a table in tables.py. And add that table to your view as usual. With the added table you may try order_by which is supported in django-tables2.

```
**tables.py**

import django_tables2 as tables
from .models import Person

class PersonTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html'

**views.py**
from django.shortcuts import render
from django_tables2 import RequestConfig
from .tables import PersonTable

def people_listing(request):
    config = RequestConfig(request)
    table = PersonTable(Person.objects.all())
    table.order_by = 'name'
    return render(request, 'data/person.html', {'table': table})
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't solve this issue. This will make the table initially sorted by "name" but won't maintain that as a primary sort when you want to sort on other categories